# Get/Set and Got/?

Tags: etymology

I'm a Java programmer.  We're always talking about getters and setters.

It occurred to me that the word "get" has a past tense of "got".

However, for the word "set" the past tense is still "set" (and not **sot**).

Why might this be?

Comment: Get is one of many irregular verbs, which are common. (If it were regular, it would be *getted*.) Set, let, and bet are also unchanged in the past tense. Abet, net, and vet become abetted, netted, vetted. Wet and pet can become either wet and pet or wetted and petted. Why? Because people use them like this in speech. If you look up past tense of pet, it will say "petted" is correct, but since 'pet' is being used, it is gaining acceptance (in the US, at least.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial answer is - because they are both irregular, and not in the same way. If they were regular, they would be **getted* and **setted*.

Less trivially, even though these verbs look very similar today, they were quite different historically.

*Get* was one of the big class of verbs in Germanic languages that are called ["strong verbs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb). These verbs exhibit [ablaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut), a regular vowel variation in their forms. For example, *break*/*broke*, *cleave*/*clove*, *ride*/*rode*, *drive*/*drove*, *swear*/*swore* are all in this class still.

*Set* (like most of English verbs today) was a weak verb, one that did not exhibit ablaut. Its past tense really would have been *setted*, but the two dentals in a row were difficult to pronounce. Difficult-to-pronounce words are likely to get simplified if used frequently (and this word is frequent indeed). This happened really early, even before English was English. There is no historical reason why the past of *set* would be **sot*.

(Thanks to Janus Bahs Jacquet for setting me straight on the timeline of changes. )

Comment: The past of _set_ was never _setted_. In Proto-Germanic, it was regularly weak (inf. _*satjana-_, 3sg pres _*satiþi_, 3sg pret _*satidē_); but the _*i_ was syncopated away and the two dentals merged early on, and already in Old English, the past tense was _sette_. When _setted_ has been used, it has been as a regularising innovation, not as a remnant of an earlier form.